# VBA Offset difficulties

Tags: vba, offset

I have fRange stored as range. Now I want fRange to go 1 down and 1 to the right. From here input boxes need to pop-up. Every time an input box is filled in it needs to move to the right until the cell has an other color.

The problem that I have is that everything I put in the input box, comes in the wrong cell.
Have this now, so think there is something wrong with the offset

```
i = 3
u = 1
fRange = fRange.Offset(1, u)

Do While Cells(1, i).Interior.Color = RGB(69, 105, 142)


fRange = InputBox("Add price", Cells(1, i))


i = i + 1
u = u + 1


Loop
```

Answer (score 1):

### Please see [VBA Best Practices documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/1107/vba-best-practices#t=201705281947292003064)

---

You're missing the `Set` keyword. If you used `Option Explicit` at the top of your modules and declared your variables you wouldn't have this problem.

`fRange` is a `Range` object. Objects have to be `Set` in VBA.

```
i = 3
u = 1
Set fRange = fRange.Offset(1, u)

Do While Cells(1, i).Interior.Color = RGB(69, 105, 142)


fRange = InputBox("Add price", Cells(1, i))


i = i + 1
u = u + 1


Loop
```

Comment: `fRange = InputBox("Add price", Cells(1, i))` was probably correct -
 implicitly using `fRange.Value`.  (But I think the `Set fRange` is probably meant to be within the `Do`.)

Comment: @YowE3K aha yes that would make more sense, I'll edit my example

Comment: But maybe it is `Set fRange = fRange.Offset(1, 0)` inside the `Do`?  (I think the OP should rewrite it to just use one variable - either `i` or `u` - not both.)

Comment: @YowE3K The logic is definitely wrong, `u` is never used and the loop looks at `Cells` instead of `fRange` - also as you've pointed out `fRange` isn't set to a new range at any point. I feel like correcting all that is just handing it on a plate to the OP instead of encouraging them to learn best practice first though.

Comment: I suspect that row 1 is a heading, and `fRange` is probably initially pointing to a row that is applicable to a date, and that the offset `fRange` is probably meant to just be referring to `Cells(r, i)` where r is that row number.  But it is impossible to tell from the question, so the OP will have to work out that for themself.